# getActivity after onAttach android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity

I am trying to get the activity in a fragment as I keep getting a `null pointer exception` on my `getActivity.finish()`.

I am trying to achieve this with the below:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    mContext = context;
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mContext = null;
}
```

In `super.onAttach(activity)` the `activity` word comes up red with the error: `cannot resolve symbol activity`

So do I need to set this equal too: `Activity activity = RepairActivity repairActivity` or something similar?

And once set how would I call the `getActivity.finish()`? would this automatically be picked up by after the `onAttach()`?

I am calling the activity like this:

```
android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

RepairFragment newFragment = new RepairFragment();

newFragment.device = device;
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.content_frame, newFragment)
    .commit();
```

Help appreciated

Comment: May or may not related, what are you trying to achieve with `mContext = context`? Just so you know you can call `getContext` from a fragment.

Comment: It came with the answer from a question on here I was looking at. I plan to use it but it's more of a side thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you saying about `RepairActivity` ? can't understand. But,

You can Finish your activity using `mContext`. Like,

```
((Activity)mContext).finish();
```

Comment: I'll give that a crack